# How to create ruby text (Japanese furigana) with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to build an iOS app with Japanese text and I want to display some Furigana over my Kanji. Meaning I need to show ruby text.

I am using SwiftUI and have absolutely zero knowledge of UIKit.

I have read that there are some ways to make this possible in UIKit, however I am still a rookie that started with SwiftUI and still have a lot to learn.

So my question is: is it even possible in SwiftUI? If not, is there a way to connect something from UIKit to make this work?

Thanks a lot in advance! Have a wonderful day :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009855/is-it-possible-to-type-in-furigana-and-ruby-characters-using-unicode. I expect this is impossible with stock tools. You would probably need to implement it by hand. This is likely a great deal of work, requiring CoreText at a minimum. I doubt UIKit can do it. Best of luck; it's a very interesting problem and would certainly teach you a lot about text layout. But I doubt there's an easy solution (unless there's a library somewhere on github that happens to do it).

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/71122383/12299030?

Comment: I came across this library on github: https://github.com/JustinWhiteDeveloper/laughing-octo-adventure  if this does not address your needs, maybe some of its  ideas can useful to create your own furigana lib.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `NSAttributedString` with `kCTRubyAnnotationAttributeName` to "add" the furigana on top of the kanji. There are lots of answers on StackOverflow about this. Here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54294243/532368

The problem is that SwiftUI `Text` won't work with `NSAttributedString`, so you need to create a `UIViewRepresentable` that uses a `UILabel` to display the attributed string with the ruby annotation correctly. You can find an example (and explanations) in the [Attributed Strings with SwiftUI](https://swiftui-lab.com/attributed-strings-with-swiftui/) article by The SwiftUI Lab.

That should give the desired result and allow you to display the furigana on top of the kanji.

[image]

Update: I haven't tried, but it seems the [ApolloZhu/RubyAttribute](https://github.com/ApolloZhu/RubyAttribute)
 project on GitHub provides the solution you need as a library.